# How to update image View during UIView Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I would like to change `image` in `imageView` during the animation. I have an `imageView` and my animation brings this `imageView` down. During this animation I need to load new photo into this `imageView` (after downloading from the Internet) but in any time when I try to do it this `imageView` **comes back to the first position**. How can I load new image without this issue?

My code:

load image function in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewModel.downloadImage({ [weak self] image in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.userImageView.image = image
        }
    })
}
```

Animation Method which i start in `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .allowAnimatedContent, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { [unowned self] _ in
            self.userProfileImageView.center.y = 300
        }, completion: nil) 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your image view is positioned in the storyboard using autolayout constraints. When you change the image view's image, that causes layout to happen; that means that the autolayout constraints take over and position the image view where it was before the animation started.

The moral is simple: do not attempt to animate a view's `center` (or `frame` or `bounds`) if that view is positioned by autolayout constraints. You can animate its *constraints* instead.